# How to remove certain lists from a list of lists using python?

Tags: python, list

I can not figure out why my code does not filter out lists from a predefined list.
I am trying to remove specific list using the following code.

```
data = [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
data = [x for x in data if x[0] != 1 and x[1] != 1]

print data
```

My result:

```
data = [[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

Expected result:

```
data = [[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
```

Comment: In `[1, 2, 1]`, `x[0] == 1` so it automatically disqualifies it. And so on and so forth...

Comment: To match the way you're thinking of the problem, use: `if not (x[0] == 1 and x[1] == 1)`

Comment: You're welcome. Note that it's logically equivalent to using `or`, as the other guys suggested: because `not (A and B)` == `(not A) or (not B)`

Comment: Turned the above into an answer, if you feel like accepting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what the OP wants.

```
data = [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]

data = [x for x in data if x[:2] != [1,1]]
print data

data = [x for x in data if ((x[0],x[1]) != (1,1))]   
print data
```

Comment: Good one as well! But this is not so well adaptable if I would want to filter by 1st and 3rd value of list instead.

Comment: How about the second solution.

Answer (score 3):

`and` is wrong, use `or`

```
data = [x for x in data if x[0] != 1 or x[1] != 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`and` is only true if both sides are true values. Perhaps you want...

```
data = [x for x in data if x[0] != 1 or x[1] != 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a small logic error. To match the way you're thinking of the problem, use:

```
if not (x[0] == 1 and x[1] == 1)
```

Note that this is logically equivalent to using `or`, as the other guys suggested:

```
not (A and B) == (not A) or (not B)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code "or" should be used in the place of "and". And "and" is used if u want to execute both the values. Example:

```
data = [x for x in data if x[0] != 1 or x[1] != 1]
```